# Execute Web Jobs from ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have c# console application which is using for some long running task. In my local system I am executing it from ASP.Net MVC 5 controller by System.Diagnostics.Process class. Now we are going it to implement it into azure as our site is deployed in azure in development mode.

I am new to azure so don't how to do it.However study several article I have found that I can upload my console application as web jobs. I can run web jobs as trigger i.e. ondemand.

But now my question is how can execute this web job from MVC controller as I need to pass some argument from controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up your web site to push an item to an Azure Queue, and then have your web job be triggered every time an item is pushed to the queue.

There is some information, including code samples for how to do that on http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs.

Comment: Thanks Andres, I have implemented this and its works. Though I have question that I need to run this console application as long as around 1+ hour, so if this web job will execute full time or I need to implement it as worker role like trailmax says.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no direct link between WebSite and WebJob, even though they are executed in the same application pool. And the best way would be to post a message to a queue from you MVC app. And on the other end have your WebJob to check for the queue for new messages. Just like Andres already said.

This will not be instant, but easy to implement and cheap.

If you need instant reaction from your console app, you'll need to implement your background tasks as Worker Roles and deploy as a separate VMs, and have there some sort of network communication going on, so you can always reach out for your worker role via TCP.

Comment: There is one important link which is the file system, they both have access to the same one.